# Create new line in row header of my custom JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rowheader

I have some problem to put lines in row header of my custom JTable.

I create this JTable with this code:

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;


public class Form {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        List<String> visibleColumns = new ArrayList<String>();

        // THIS COLUMN NEED TO BE IN 2 LINES
        visibleColumns.add("Cod Type\nGroup");
        visibleColumns.add("Name");

        DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(visibleColumns.toArray(),5);
        JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);

        Panel panel = new Panel();
        panel.setBounds(5, 5, 352, 232);
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.NORTH);

        // Set Row Header
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);

        // Set Column Header
        JPanel columnHeader = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                JScrollBar sb = new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.VERTICAL);
                return new Dimension(sb.getPreferredSize().width, 10);
            }
        };
        scroll.setRowHeaderView(columnHeader);

        // Set 3D effects to scroll pane
        JPanel left = new JPanel();
        left.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));
        scroll.setCorner(ScrollPaneConstants.UPPER_LEFT_CORNER, left);
        JPanel right = new JPanel();
        right.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));
        scroll.setCorner(ScrollPaneConstants.UPPER_RIGHT_CORNER, right);

        panel.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //Setting column size
        TableColumnModel tcm = table.getColumnModel();

        tcm.getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        tcm.getColumn(0).setWidth(73);
        tcm.getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(73);

        tcm.getColumn(1).setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        tcm.getColumn(1).setWidth(222);
        tcm.getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(222);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(350, 180);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

But I need that the text `"Cod Type\nGroup"` create a new line row header, like this figure:

Ps: Note that the text is centered.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: also avoid the use of `Null Layout` instead take a look at [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: `I tryed some codes but not work.` what didn't worked?

Comment: Maybe I can use <html> and <br> but I tryed to use that and doesnt work.
The text was not centered and did not fit in the header.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `HTML` like this

```
visibleColumns.add("<html><center>Cod Type<br>Group");
visibleColumns.add("Name");
```

[image]

And also take a look at [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) because `swing` is designed to use them instead of `null layouts`.